# How do I display a table which has another table as a variable in app designer app in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

The code below generates a matlab table which has another table as one of its variables.

```
test = [1;2;3];
test2 = [5;6;7];
test3 = [9;10;11];
tmp = table(test, test2, test3);
merged = mergevars(tmp,{'test','test2'},'NewVariableName','Combined','MergeAsTable',true);
```

I want to display a similar table in an app I am building in app designer. I do not find any info how to do that. I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

```
app.UITable.Data = merged
```

does generate an empty table in the GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to another table in Matlab app designer has some limitations. You can do it for every normal table, but if you have a merged column in your table, you can't do it.
I have tried it before. It is impossible in "UITable" to use a merged column.
You can do it at the Java level.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).